# convert div into image using html2canvas (Does not render full div)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Question:

I try to use html2canvas to convert my div into images, I able to generate images, but it will not render the full div it will stick until row 93 after that the rest it will show blank. Hence, the total row will have 95 and the height of it is around 16638px. Does anyone have face this issue before? I really no idea how to solve this issue. Any expert can help me on this? How to render full div into the image no matter how many rows I have. Below is my code.

**html**

```
<div class="row convertpic">
        <div class="col-12">
          
            <div class="card-body card padding10">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div>
                    
                        @for ($k = 0 ; $k < 95; $k++)
                            {{-- @php
                            $sum  = ($val->{1}->PreviousAllTotal + $val->total);
                            @endphp --}}
            
                            <div>
                                <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: -25px;">
                                    {{-- <div class="col-md-1"></div> --}}
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input type="text" class="bodercol fontbold text-center form-control" id="" value="1" disabled>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" class="bodercol colorgreen fontbold form-control text-center" value="1"  class="text-center"  disabled style="margin-top: 8px;">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" class="bodercol fontbold text-center form-control"  value="1" disabled style="margin-top: 7px;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                {{-- <div class="col-md-1"></div> --}}
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" class="bodercol fontbold text-center form-control" value="1" disabled style="margin-top: -14px;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                        @endfor
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>     
        </div>  
    </div>
```

**css**

```
.convertpic2{
  width: auto !important;
  height: auto !important;
  max-height: auto !important;
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```

**javascript**

```
html2canvas($(".convertpic").addClass('convertpic2'), {
                allowTaint:true,
                taintTest:false,
                height: $(".convertpic").outerHeight() + 20,    
                scale:1,
                dpi: 144,
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg", 1.0);
                    downloadURI(myImage, "{{$data->data->roundet[0]->round}}"+dt.getTime()+".jpg");
                    $(".convertpic").removeClass('convertpic2');
                    $('.resultsloading').hide();
            }   
            });
```

outcome
[image]

Comment: Have you experimented with different numbers of rows? For instance, if you only try to create 50 rows, do all 50 rows show up, or does that become 48 complete rows with 2 left blank?

Comment: ya, no problem with that, it will only start show blank after row 93.

Comment: I wonder if 16384 is a relevant limit here, which is 2^14? Try tweaking your CSS so all 95 rows fit in less than 16384 pixels and see what happens.